# Virtualmin "Command to run after making changes to a server" differentiate between add/edit/delete

Tags: virtualmin

I'm using Virtualmin, and I have a command set up under **Virtualmin > Module Config > Actions Upon Server and user creation > Command to run after making changes to a server**

This command is designed to perform a few additional steps after the account is set up. However, the action is called every time the account is modified, and also gets called when the account is deleted. The actions it performs should only be done when the account is first created.

How can my custom command know which action is being performed? Is there an environment variable which determines if the action is creation, alteration, or deletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in the [Virtualmin documentation](http://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/id,template_variable_listing#variables_in_domain_modification_scripts): There's an environment variable `$VIRTUALSERVER_ACTION` available to the scripts which will contain one of:

- `CREATE_DOMAIN`   Set when a virtual
  server is being created.
- `DELETE_DOMAIN`   Set when a virtual
  server is being deleted.
- `MODIFY_DOMAIN`   Set when a virtual
  server is being changed, such as
  getting a new password, features or
  quota.
- `DISABLE_DOMAIN`  Set when a
  virtual server is being disabled via
  the UI or for exceeding its bandwidth
  limit.
- `ENABLE_DOMAIN`   Set when a
  virtual server is being enabled via
  the UI or for dropping back under its
  bandwidth limit.
- `RESTORE_DOMAIN`  Set
  when a virtual server is being
  restored from a backup.